# Typescript - generic sort array of objects by dynamic property name

Tags: typescript, sorting, generics, dynamic, properties

I would like to create generic, typed method that will sort array of objects by number which is under dynamic property name in each object.

This is what I have till now:

```
export const sortByNumber = <T, K extends keyof T>(
  items: T[],
  dateFieldName: K,
) => items.sort((a: T, b: T) => a[dateFieldName] - b[dateFieldName])
```

problem with this method is that in `items.sort` when I subtract `a[...] - b[...]` compiler tells me that those should be numbers. I agree, but how do I specify it in method definition?

Example of what I want to achieve:

```
const iWantToSortThis = [
    { name: 'some', example: 3 }, 
    { name: 'name', example: 1 }, 
    { name: 'whatever', example: 2 }
]

sortByNumber(iWantToSortThis, 'example') // gets sorted nicely
```

but also

```
const anotherArrayToSort = [
    { name: 'some', prop: 'abc', anotherExample: 3 }, 
    { name: 'name', prop: 'xyz', anotherExample: 1 }, 
    { name: 'whatever', prop: 'asd', anotherExample: 2 }
]

sortByNumber(anotherArrayToSort, 'anotherExample') 
// also gets sorted nicely even though objects have different 
// shape and fieldName is different then in first example.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the reverse, first get the type of `dateFieldName` as a literal type, then constraint `T` with object type containing one prop `K` with type `number`.

```js
export const sortByNumber = <K extends string, T extends Record<K, number>>(
  items: T[],
  dateFieldName: K,
) => items.sort((a: T, b: T) => a[dateFieldName] - b[dateFieldName])

const iWantToSortThis = [
    { name: 'some', example: 3 }, 
    { name: 'name', example: 1 }, 
    { name: 'whatever', example: 2 }
]

sortByNumber(iWantToSortThis, 'example')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=41#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM71dGAhAngOQFcBbAI2CjgF44AeAaTlBmGQBNU50oBLZAcwA0cACpMQLdpwBKwJFDYNhyEuSgA+dQAoAUHDg8WxVAC5RAbQC6gvXDYBDFgDEewADZt894sDP0bAJTU6gZGqAB0mLBaWvZmIsKk8UFUIfbmDs6uHl4+lnAAtHCkGY7ALu6e3sCWATo6SGjwPADq9sgwIhAAylgiABY8nDTmtvoA3nDI1WYA5Jg+s8Kg3mBuvnAAzHAAvsJjcJPTPnPHwEviq+tmAIy7+-oTUzNwswDu-WUAbhQXK8RrDYAJl2Oks9SiOAIqgoWla7U6PT6g1Qwlm-0BswCQA)